# Kendo.MVC Filter

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid which has a kendo filter, I have set extra(false) in the kendo filter and removed the dropdown using the below code. Here the filtering is happening only when I give complete value, instead I need to filter with starting value

```
---------------------------script start
<script type="text/javascript">

function filterMenuInit(e) {
    var firstValueDropDown = e.container.find("select:eq(0)").data("kendoDropDownList");

    setTimeout(function () {
        firstValueDropDown.wrapper.hide();
    });
}

</script>

 ------------------------script End
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model) //Bind the grid to ViewBag.Products
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {


      columns.Bound(Commission => Commission.CreatedDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}").Filterable(f => f.UI("DateTimeFilter"));
      columns.Bound(Commission => Commission.Status);
      columns.Bound(Commission => Commission.Branch);
      columns.Bound(Commission => Commission.ULN);
      columns.Bound(Commission => Commission.MgrAmount);
      columns.Bound(Commission => Commission.PayFrequency);
      columns.Bound(Commission => Commission.CalcBasis);
  })
                        .Pageable() // Enable paging
                        .Sortable() // Enable sorting
                        .Filterable(f => f.Extra(false))

                      .Events(e => e.FilterMenuInit("filterMenuInit"))    
                      .Pageable(pager => pager
                          .PageSizes(new[] { 5, 10, 15 }))


                          )
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to use the Filterable UI functionality. See the demo page here http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/filter-menu-customization.html

Comment: actually my requirement is to filter the column without those dropdown's so i made extra(false) n removed the extra dropdown,after doing all these things search is not happening for half data's,its working only when i give full data.hw to search with partial data's? Means  instead of typing stack overflow completely i will type s n the stack overflow appears in the grid